# Base address of WinAPI across all versions of Windows

Tags: c, winapi, memory-address, portable-executable

Let's assume I hardcode a given address for a Windows API into my executable. Can I assume that this address will evaluate to the correct API across all Windows versions (XP, 7, Vista, Server07/12, etc)?

If not, is it possible for me to make this so without obtaining the address before-hand (GetProcAddress or enumerating dll ordinals)?

Would I have to provide a prepackaged version of the .dll with the given address inside my application?

Comment: No, no and no. If you feel the need to do this, you're doing something very wrong. (With regard to your last (third) question, recent versions of Windows will actually prevent you from doing so.)

Comment: DLLs get relocated to dynamically assigned addresses.

Comment: Hey guys, my 2 cents: obviously the question was posted by someone new to low level Windows programming; for a newbie, IMO this is a very good question and where to find the answer in official sources may not be so apparent.  As such, why all the downvotes? I would rather the the OP ask the question rather than such a mistake be made in production code. BTW Great answer @David Heffernan

Answer (score 3):

The answer to all your questions is no.

Relative function entry point address vary from one version of Windows to the next, vary even on system updates.

The DLLs themselves have base  addresses that vary from version to version. And finally, DLLs need not load at their desired base  address. They may be relocated.

Finally, you cannot redistribute system DLLs. Not only does that contravene the license, but it won't work because system DLLs are only compatible with the version of Windows that they are delivered with.

Whatever your problem is, hardcoding function entry points is not the solution.

Comment: It is perhaps also worth nothing that by default modern Windows systems will [intentionally relocate the systems DLLs at random](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) on reboot.